# How to install pmdarima in anaconda prompt. Tried conda install pmdarima not worked

Tags: python, anaconda, time-series, conda, pyramid-arima

conda install pmdarima

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

Answer (score 4):

> pip install pmdarima

Issue resolved.

Answer (score 4):

Following worked for me to install the package with anaconda:

`conda install -c saravji pmdarima`

Answer (score 3):

if pip install pmdarima fails to you,
try as a user:

```
pip install pmdarima --user
```

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

```
conda install -n [NameOfVEnv] -c saravji pmdarima
```

Where [`-c`](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/install.html#Channel%20Customization) stands for "channel" which is

> the locations where Navigator and conda look for packages. ([Source](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/tutorials/manage-channels/))

and [`-n`](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/install.html#Target%20Environment%20Specification) for "Name of environment".

I just tried here (on CentOS 7) and it worked fine.

---

**Option 2**

An alternative, if one is using `Windows 10`, is to access `Anaconda Prompt` **for the environment that you are working with** as admin:

[image: Access Anaconda Prompt as admin]

And run

```
conda install -c saravji pmdarima
```

I just tried here (on Windows 10 64-bit) and it worked fine.

---

**Option 3**

As it is suggested on [pmdarima's repo on GitHub](https://github.com/alkaline-ml/pmdarima)

```
pip install pmdarima
```

---

You may need to install dependencies (in all the options), but it asks you in the prompt window. If it appears, you will need to enter `Y`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I tried installing with "conda install pmdarima".
Simply using "python -m pip install pmdarima --user" worked for me on anaconda prompt